# Java store matches in array

Tags: java

Hi I would like to store my matches in my array however constantly getting errors of nullpointer or out of bounds.

```
    final  String mcontentURI[] = new String[count];
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(content_val);
        if (m.find()) {
            mcontentURI[i] = (m.group(i+1));


        }
    }
```

Comment: There's far too little information here to help.  We have no idea what size `count` is, or what specific errors you get for specific inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you keep re-compiling the same regex, the group number is going to stay the same. You can put it at different indexes of the array, though:

```
final String mcontentURI[] = new String[count];
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(content_val); // Use different strings here
    if (m.find()) {
        mcontentURI[i] = m.group(1);
    }
}
```

Note that `mcontentURI[i]` would remain `null` for indexes for which the pattern did not match.

If you want to search the same string, do this:

```
final String mcontentURI[] = new String[count];
final Pattern p = Pattern.compile("src=\"(.*?)\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(content_val);
int i = 0;
while (i < count && m.find()) {
    mcontentURI[i++] = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! but it's giving me the same strings in the array for the first part of the answer

Comment: @rustymolle That happens if you keep passing the same string for the match (see my comment about using different strings). For using the same string use the second part of the answer.

Comment: ahh yes I see. Thank you!